Teen-aged girl arrives in a small town and is tormented by other students at school
I saw this movie long time ago, so I will try my best to remember what it was about and describe it.
The movie, as I remember, was kinda low-budget, so it could be pretty unknown.
Story is about a teen-aged girl who arrives at a small town (like a road, plain & forest and few houses near it, atmosphere of that place was European), the girl was not very popular as I remember, in some party a guy touched her with his penis and when he came to school there was a poster about the girl "Welcome Cock Anna" or another name such as Onna, can't recall it. 
That's pretty much what I can recall.

Approximate year\decade? Was it in English? Where\when did you see it?


TURN ME ON, DAMMIT! is a pretty wacky and fun, Norwegian coming-of-age film from back in 2011, based on a book. The story is set in a remote town in Norway. The female lead, Alma gets "poked" by a guy and the story spreads like wildfire where she is then being made fun of and being called "Dick Alma". Though it handles serious issues, they're handled in an approachable and non-melodramatic way. Basically it's a story about a girl's sexual awakening, as far as I remember...
It should be the film you're looking for. 

Can you include any reasons or similarities why you think this "should be the film"? Personally, I didn't infer that the movie being asked about was a wacky and fun film, but they didn't really specify. I just guessed it was a drama from the use of the word "tormented" in the question's title.

After Lucia perhaps? Alejandra and her dad Roberto have just moved to town. She is new at school, he has a new job. Starting over is sometimes complicated when you have left so much behind. It's from 2012 Spanish movie. Since you can only vaguely remember the film, I thought that this might be what you're looking for.

Is there anything else (other than new girl in town) that makes you think this might be the movie?

Well, it's an european movie. And though the main lead is sought after at the beginning, this rapidly changes after a party where all class mates turn against her. Also, since you mentioned the name might begin with "A..", I just took a guess. But if it's not the movie, then you haven't lost anything either by that (After Lucia, is after all, a good film). Good luck then. Tootles, Monticora

I didn't mention the name, as I'm not the OP. You can see the posts are tagged with the names of the person who wrote them. (Which also means you don't need to sign a post.) You should edit your answer to include this party information and anything else you think might help the person (not me) who asked the question. I suggest checking out the Tour to get a better idea of how to ask and answer questions. We're not a typical discussion forum.

After Lucia is not the movie, but it would be great to watch if it had proper translation. "I just guessed it was a drama from the use of the word "tormented" in the question's title." - Moderators changed my title. Original  inlcuded ( Drama, Comedy* )
